# Array: Compile Error. Wrong number of variables

Tags: arrays, vba

I am learning VBA at school and having trouble with some basics.
I populated cells A1 through D1 with random integers.
I want to sum them and put the solution in E1.

```
Sub Add_Four_Numbers()
Dim CBArray(3) As Double
For i = 1 To 4
    Cells(i, 4) = gerry(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 4))
Next i
End Function
```

I keep getting:

> Compile Error. Wrong number of variables

I have tried to fix dimension of the array with no success.
Can someone advise?
Thank you.

Comment: I keep getting this message:Compile Error. Wrong number of variables

Comment: Have you check the method `gerry`? How many parameter it take?

Comment: @CactusBlanket what is `gerry` ? is it a `Function` you have ? if it is, then share the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the school assignment was, but there are several ways to sum the values in Cells A1-D1, and have the result in Cell E1.

In the code below, there are 3 methods of summing them up.

(not sure why you are using an array, was that a part of the assignment ?)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add_Four_Numbers()

Dim Sht             As Worksheet
Dim i               As Long

' always set your cells to a sheet varibale >> modify "Sheet1" to your Sheet's name
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

' option 1: using WorksheetFunction SUM and your pre-defined Range
With Sht
    .Range("E1").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("A1:D1"))
End With


' option 2: using WorksheetFunction SUM and Cells reference inside
With Sht
    .Range("E1").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, 3), .Cells(1, 4))
End With


' option 3: using a For loop
With Sht
    .Range("E1").Value = 0
    For i = 1 To 4
        .Range("E1").Value = .Range("E1").Value + .Cells(1, i)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```